# Default Language Android Application

Tags: android, localization

I'm new to android. I have developed an app and published on Play. My app's default language is Turkish. But when I published I didn't see the Turkish description part. There is English as default selected language.

How can I write a Turkish description?

Edit: Here is an screenshot for being clearer.

[image: languages]

Comment: I couldn't see turkish. Did you see?

Answer (score 0):

In the Apps Developer Console you cann add langauages and set the Default langauage. Just search for the "Add languages" link, there you have to add your turkish description.

Answer (score 0):

You can not translate your app description with Turkis Language.But you can translate your description with language which given by Google Developer Console.

Go To The Your Publisher Account->Language->Add Language->Select Language whihc you want translate ->Check Fill fields with auto translation from... ->Ok.

Comment: so you can not translate it.If your want force fully write your description then use google translater & convert your english translate to turkish(If Google Translater Support).

Answer (score 0):

Try new design. When you try to edit your app, there is a button "Add translation" at the top of the page. There is Turkish option there.